# Returning DateTime in the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ without creating a string object

Tags: c#, wcf, datetime

Is there a way to return a DateTime object in the format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ without having to convert the DateTime object to a string. You see, I am passing this object to a web service consumer that is looking for a dateTime object, but I think its because I am passing a string, the web consumer is not recognizing the date. Is this possible?

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't have a format.  It's simply a value.  You can choose to pass the raw value to a service that expects a raw value, or format it as a string if the service expects a formatted string.  Edit your question and add the code that sends the `DateTime` and we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

That is usually handled for you if you specify the datatype in the interface as DateTime. You can convert a date/time to string manually with .ToString("O") to get the so-called round-trip format, which is what you show but with the time-zone offset. To get the UTC version of that, to ToString("O") on the UTC-converted datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "2023-01-24T09:27:39.104Z";
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

Comment: The OP wants to go from a `DateTime` - not to one.